# Find Prospects with more than 1 Closed / Won Opportunity in Pardot Salesforce

Tags: opportunity, pardot

I want to assign Prospects with more than 1 closed won Opportunity to a dynamic list.

How can we iterate on related Opportunities of Prospects and check if they are closed won and then assign to dynamic list.

Any inputs will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Salesforce as the CRM, your best bet would be to create a custom field on the Contact, have APEX update this the be the count of closed won Opportunities, then sync that field to a Custom Pardot field.